# Google is in German instead of English

Tags: google-search, localization, firefox

As you can see in the following picture, firefox's language is German.

[image]

Searching for 'google maps' brings as first result  www.google.**de**/map.

What i did was to follow the steps in this tutorial: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-interface-other-languages-language-pack

1. I have installed the English (US) version of the browser
2. In the add-ons Manager, the Language panel shows English language pack
   [image]
3. When trying to change the language of the user interface, i type about:config in the address bar; searching for ' intl.locale.requested' brings no result

There are other entries such as intl.accept_languages, but the tutorial does not use them. Anyway, this entry  is set to English
[image]

What can i do about this problem? While the location of my company is outside Germany, the website https://www.whoismyisp.org/ identifies the location of my ISP as a german city.

EDIT: I also tried this approach:

4. I went to https://www.google.co.in/preferences?hl=en, and changed the Region Settings from Current Region to United States. Still the same result

[image]

2nd EDIT: several more attempts:

5. I typed 'about:config' in the address bar, I added the entry 'intl.locale.requested' with the value 'en-GB', and I also modified the wifi uri to point to a New York location. I also set 'geo.enabled' to false, but the results are still in german. *I did not forget to restart the browser after these changes.*

[image]

As pointed out [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147166/how-can-you-fake-geolocation-in-firefox) , it appears that websites derive the location based on the IP address. The only way to bypass this is to use a proxy - which might be against my company's policy, and the internet connection is pretty slow already.

Comment: Firefox is in English, websites are in German. It's an important distinction, because these have completely different causes.

Comment: You're connecting from German IP, so google detects it and shows you german page. Go to google.co.uk to be sure to find google in English

Comment: even the page https://www.google.co.uk/ is in german

Comment: Are you searching from Firefox’ address bar or search bar?

Comment: Honestly I think Google eliminated this kind of functionality in the last year or two. Now language and locality seem to be fixed by user location. Are you logged in to you account? Same logged in or out, or on a system where cookies and off-line data are not saved?

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, try the same search "google maps" on [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/). German sites listed? Then under "All Regions" select US or UK. Any better?

Comment: @Daniel B : it's the same; the two bars are synchronized; every time I enter a query in the address bar, it appears in the google search bar, too

Comment: @user3169 : I am not logged in on any account; I did not test as logged in to some account; firefox currently saves cookies

Comment: @user3169 : i did try DuckDuckGo, and it went perfectly, even with All Regions selected; I also checked other search engines: Yahoo Search brings english results, Bing brings german results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&gl=en

Underneath the buttons should be a line containing

`Google offered in: English`

[image: There should be an English option]

Click on `English`

Comment: The line containing "google offered in" only appears from time to time, its inconsistent, i don't know why it doesn't always appear. When it appeared, i was able to change the language to English, then I changed it back to German, i refreshed the page, and now its gone. How can i bring it back?

Comment: Try this: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&gl=en

Comment: Yes, now it works fine. The appended parameters do the job

Comment: initially, this solution looked like an ugly workaround, to have to paste this custom url everytime in the search box; but i mapped the homepage to this url, and everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

You confuse Fx language (UI) from pages language; in particular, you confuse google preferences (specific page) from general `Accept-Language` header value your Fx sends. I won't put click path here, as such things change over the time, so for now just look [here](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/help/how-to-set-browser-language.html), [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/64407/how-to-change-firefox-language/) or [here](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/help/how-to-set-browser-language.html).

Comment: I did this already. The language is set to ENGLISH(US), and no other languages are present